# Replace %20 with - in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
Route::get('product/details/{name}','ProductController@viewProduct');
```

So when the load it shows like `abc.com/product/details/double&20butter&20cheese`
But i want it shows like `abc.com/product/details/double-butter-cheese`
I know there is a helper call **Str::slug** But i'm confused how do i use it in route.

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't the fault of the route definition as you've shown, it's whatever is creating the URL to that route. It looks like you're passing in the product's name as it's written for humans (with spaces), instead of a slug.

Answer (score 1):

The line of code where you are generating url using the the product-name, it should be like:

```
$slug = str_slug('double butter cheese', '-');
```

or variable in which you have stored the value of product-name like:

```
$slug = str_slug($productName, '-');
```